# Get posts from people you are following (php)

Tags: php, mysql, post, feed

What I am trying to accomplish is to fill a news feed full of posts from friends of $username which is the session username.

The sql does not seem to work however.

```
SELECT posts.*            
FROM posts
INNER JOIN follow            
ON posts.by=follow.person_being_followed          
WHERE follow.person_following = $username
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

this is also the code for the page to echo this information

```
        <?

    $get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT posts.*            
FROM posts
INNER JOIN follow            
ON posts.by=follow.person_being_followed          
WHERE follow.person_following = $username
ORDER BY posts.id DESC");
    while ($post_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_posts)) {

        include './includes/newsfeed/postdetails.tpl';
        include './includes/newsfeed/likeinfo.tpl';
        include './includes/newsfeed/fandlname.tpl';
        include './includes/newsfeed/deletepostbutton.tpl';

    ?>


        <div style='display: inline-block;width: 560px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);'>
        <a style='float: left;' href='./profile.php?u=<?
        echo $post_by;
    ?>'><img src='' height='50px' width='50px'/></a>
        <div style='float: right; width: 500px;'>
        <p style='color: rgb(59, 152, 96);font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.38;font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;'><a style='color: rgb(59, 152, 96);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.38;text-decoration: none;' href='./profile.php?u=<?
        echo $post_by;
    ?>'><?
        echo "$fnamepost  $lnamepost";
    ?></a></p>
        <p style='color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.38;
    font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;'><?
        echo $post_content;
    ?></p>

        <div style='margin-top: 5px;'><a href='./scripts/like.php?pid=<?
        echo $post_id;
    ?>' style='color:rgb(109, 180, 137);
    font-size: 11px;line-height: 1.28;'><?
        echo "$likedornot ($countlikes)";
    ?></a><a href='#' class='comment_button' style='margin-left: 10px;color:rgb(109, 180, 137);
    font-size: 11px;line-height: 1.28;'><?
        echo "Comment";
    ?></a><?
        echo $deletecodevariable;
    ?></div>

    <?
        include './includes/newsfeed/comments.tpl';
        ?>
    </div></div>
    <?
    }
    ?>
```

mysql table for follow

[image: also this is my table for follow]

mysql table for posts

[image: and this is my table for posts]

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: I'll post the entire page code with the echo